# Java: Path vs File

Tags: java, file-io, path, nio

For new applications written in Java 7, is there any reason to use a [`java.io.File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object any more or can we consider it deprecated?

I believe a [`java.nio.file.Path`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) can do everything a [`java.io.File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) can do and more.

Answer (score 194):

**Long story short:**

`java.io.File` will most likely *never* be deprecated / unsupported. That said, `java.nio.file.Path` is part of the more modern `java.nio.file` lib, and does everything `java.io.File` can, but generally in a better way, and more.

For new projects, use `Path`.

And if you ever need a `File` object for legacy, just call [Path#toFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile())

**Migrating from File to Path**

[This Oracle page highlights differences, and maps `java.io.File functionality` to `java.nio.file lib (including Path) functionality`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html)

[Article by Janice J. Heiss and Sharon Zakhour, May 2009, discussing NIO.2 File System in JDK 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/nio-139333.html)

Comment: You can read Oracle's comments on the differences here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html

Comment: Also note that "Files" (in the plural) is **not** deprecated.  It is essentially an abstract class that operates on Path objects and performs many of the features of the old File class, such as isDirectory() or exists()

Comment: Now I'm wondering: why do the new File/FolderChooser dialogs in JavaFX 8 then still use `File` instead of `Path`?

Comment: Path is an interface. To create an instance, use Paths.get(filename). It could be because of the confusion of having to write Files.exists(Paths.get(filename)) instead of new File(filename).exists() that the older API is still used.

Comment: `Path` can be more easily modified to "add children" with `resolve(...)` or "move up one level" with `getParent()`, etc. whereas `File` cannot. Essentially once you have finished modifying the Path, you'll often convert it `toFile()` so it can be sent into legacy methods such as a `FileInputStream` constructor.

Answer (score 17):

> can we consider it deprecated?

No, you *can't* consider it deprecated unless and until it is so marked in the `File` Javadoc.

Comment: Even if this is one of these "Because the RFC says so"-Answers, I would not consider it as a good answer. It's pretty obvious that File will be replace by Path. If you want to be ahead of time you can start using Path immediatly and use toFile() where needed.

Comment: @Chris Nothing has ever been removed from the JDK since they changed the AWT event model in 1.02. It isn't 'obvious' at all. It's wrong.

Comment: @EJP I just upvoted that comment of yours. However, I'm not entirely sure that you're right when you say the answer is a tautology.  The question, which should probably have been squashed for being "opinion-based", is "can we **consider** it deprecated".  Well, yes, the OP and anyone else **can**, but it isn't.

Comment: @mikerodent I suggest that's just a wilful misreading of what the question is really about. Also a partial quotation.

Comment: @EJP Sorry I would upvote. Bad manipulation on my smartphone. If you edit, I could reverse it.

Comment: @EJP Disagree. The question should have been squashed as "opinion-based".  If the words "can we consider" had been absent it wouldn't have been posed in the first place.

Comment: @mikerodent I don't understand your final sentence. You don't know what the OP would and wouldn't have 'posed'. And I don't see that the presence of the word 'can' makes any substantive difference.

Answer (score 11):

Check this article about more info - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/nio-139333.html

Basically file.Path will be the way to go from now on but as is widely known Java people tend to keep back-compatibility so I guess that's why they have left it.

Comment: Would you please update the link? I would like to read this article.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find the original article on the oracle web page. Here is a version from the wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20090601091119/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/

Comment: I found the article again on a normal Oracle side - added link to answer.

Answer (score 8):

I will complete the very good answer of `@mmcrae`.

> is there any reason to use a java.io.File object any more or can we
>   consider it deprecated?

JDK classes are very rarely deprecated.
You can see on the [the JDK 8 API deprecates list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/deprecated-list.html#class) all classes deprecated since the first JDK.
It contains only a little part of classes that the Oracle documentation and the Java community discourage to use.
`java.util.Date`, `java.util.Vector`, `java.util.Hashtable`... that are classes with so many defects are not deprecated.
But why ? 
Because conceptually something of `deprecated` means still there but discourage to use as it will very certainly be removed.
Thousands of programs rely on these bad designed classes.
For such classes, Java API developers will not give such a signal.

Answer of `@EJP` is so really right :

> Not unless and until it is so marked in the Javadoc.

So, I think that your question would make more sense in its terms : 
"As we have the choice, should we use `java.io.File` or `java.nio.file.Path` for new developments and if the answer is `java.nio.file.Path`, could you easily take advantage of `java.io.File` for legacy projects using `java.io.File` ?"

> I believe a java.nio.file.Path can do everything a java.io.File can do
>   and more.

You have the answer.

[This oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html) about legacy IO confirms your thinking.

> Prior to the Java SE 7 release, the `java.io.File` class was the
>   mechanism used for file I/O, but it had several drawbacks.
>
> Many methods didn't throw exceptions when they failed, so it was
>   impossible to obtain a useful error message. For example, if a file
>   deletion failed, the program would receive a "delete fail" but
>   wouldn't know if it was because the file didn't exist, the user didn't
>   have permissions, or there was some other problem.
>
> The rename method didn't work consistently across platforms. There was
>   no real support for symbolic links.
>
> More support for metadata was desired, such as file permissions, file
>   owner, and other security attributes.
>
> Accessing file metadata was inefficient.
>
> Many of the File methods didn't scale. Requesting a large directory
>   listing over a server could result in a hang. Large directories could
>   also cause memory resource problems, resulting in a denial of service.
>
> It was not possible to write reliable code that could recursively walk
>   a file tree and respond appropriately if there were circular symbolic
>   links.

With so many drawbacks for `java.io.File`, we need really no reason to use this class for new developments.
And even for legacy code using `java.io.File`, Oracle gives hints to use `Path`.

> Perhaps you have legacy code that uses java.io.File and would like to
>   take advantage of the java.nio.file.Path functionality with minimal
>   impact to your code.
>
> The java.io.File class provides the toPath method, which converts an
>   old style File instance to a java.nio.file.Path instance, as follows:

```
Path input = file.toPath();
```

> You can then take advantage of the rich feature set available to the
>   Path class.
>
> For example, assume you had some code that deleted a file:

```
file.delete();
```

> You could modify this code to use the Files.delete method, as follows:

```
Path fp = file.toPath();
Files.delete(fp);
```

Comment: In short, she/he can indeed **consider** it deprecated if she/he wants.

Comment: @mike rodent. Exactly. Conceptually she/he should while it is not the case in terms of Javadoc for explained reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but many existing APIs, including Java7's own standard APIs, still work only with `File` type.

Comment: Path objects can be converted to File objects using [Path.toFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile()), then use standard APIs.

Comment: So your answer is 'yes but no'?

Answer (score 3):

Java.io.File is not deprecated. Yes java.nio.file.Path is better, but as long as there are still plenty of programs and text books using Java.io.File, if only for legacy reasons, it should not be considered deprecated, its too important. Doing so would just be throwing a spanner in the works for no over all gain. For example the Android framework uses File for some of its basic file handling features, many other things do to.

Comment: He didn't ask whether `Path` was better. He asked whether `File` was deprecated.

Comment: @EJP I think you are being a little over pedantic. The OP did ask if java.io.File was deprecated and I answered that.. He also stated  "I believe a java.nio.file.Path can do everything a java.io.File can do and more."  I was merely confirming his comment, it was hardly worth a vote down.

Answer (score -1):

It is known that classes in **java.nio** package work with **Path instances**, and not **File instances**. It's recommended practice to work with the Path class if using java.nio wherever possible.

Now sometimes you will have to use the File class. That's because the method or constructor wants to File instance as a parameter, but when you do have a choice, make sure you use the **Path** over the **File**.

Answer (score -10):

> For new applications written in Java 7, is there any reason to use a
>   java.io.File object any more or can we consider it deprecated?

This is a bit like saying: "should Napoleon invade Russia, ***or*** are these Brussels sprouts really tasty?"

As to the second part of the question, you can indeed consider it deprecated. As of January 2018, it isn't deprecated.  But there's nothing to stop you ***considering*** it so.  Whether that will procure you any advantage in this life or the next is impossible to say.

Comment: I don't understand your analogy.

Comment: Any "or" question should present two logical alternatives, both of which essentially answer the same question.

Comment: Sorry, this sounds highly pedantic in this context. The idea is "I want to use `File`. Should I, yes or no?"

Comment: No offence taken. The way the question is posed invites an analysis of what's it's "really" asking, and you've given a reasonable interpretation.  But it is a loaded question.  By pointing out its curious nature I'm just drawing attention to the fact that it should really have been squashed as "opinion-based".  As to your question: "yes".  You say you want to, so use it.  The OP wanted someone to say "don't use `File`, it's a bit rubbish", but `File` is still with us five or more years later. Maybe we should celebrate that?

Comment: Yeah I agree it's a loaded question... especially since that a lot of existing 3rd party APIs still use `File` anyway. It's not going to die anytime soon.

Comment: `it isn't deprecated. But there's nothing to stop you *considering* it so` LOL.