# How to access a sub-file/folder in Java 7 java.nio.file.Path?

Tags: java, path, nio, java-7

Java 7 introduced [java.nio.file.Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) as a [possible replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903335/java-7-path-vs-file) for java.io.File.

With File, when I access a file under a specific, I would do:

```
File parent = new File("c:\\tmp");
File child = new File(parent, "child"); // this accesses c:\tmp\child
```

What's the way to do this with Path?

I supposed this will work:

```
Path parent = Paths.get("c:\\tmp");
Path child = Paths.get(parent.toString(), "child");
```

But calling `parent.toString()` seems ugly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**Use the [`resolve`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve%28java.lang.String%29) method on [`Path`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html).**

There are two methods with this name. [One](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve%28java.nio.file.Path%29) takes a relative `Path` and [the other](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve%28java.lang.String%29) a `String`.  It uses the `Path` on which it is called as a parent and appends the `String` or relative `Path` appropriately.

```
Path parent = Paths.get("c:\\tmp");
Path child = parent.resolve("child");
```

Comment: But this uses path resolution, which could potentially cause a security concern.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone finding this question looking **specifically** only for files that are within the specified path, you must be aware of path traversal attacks.

See: [Filtering upwards path traversal in Java (or Scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083397/filtering-upwards-path-traversal-in-java-or-scala/33084369#33084369)

It is **critical** that you check that the path starts with the root.

```
Path parent = Paths.get("C:\\tmp");
Path child = parent.resolve("chlid").normalize();
if (!child.startsWith(parent)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Potential Path Traversal Attack");
}
```