# Create new Path from existing Path object with NIO2

Tags: java, nio

I have a `java.nio.file.Path` object that represents some directory (e.g., `/var/log`). I want a new Path object representing a file within the directory (e.g., `/var/log/something.log`). I have been using

```
Path logDir = ...
Path logFile = Paths.get(logDir.toString(), "something.log");
```

But it seems silly to have to turn logDir into a string, then construct the new Path object. How can I get the logFile object but without using toString? E.g.,

```
Path logDir = ...
Path logFile = Paths.get(logDir, "something.log"); // Doesn't exist
```

Comment: `logDir.resolve`? Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227499/how-to-access-a-sub-file-folder-in-java-7-java-nio-file-path

Comment: Yes, exact duplicate but with a better title.

Comment: @anoopelias yup, that answers it! I voted to close this question