# Delete file with Java 7

Tags: java, java-7

I am working on one project in which I use `java.nio.*` for file operation. Basically my product is working on server now I am creating files on server using Java 7.

```
Files.createFile(path)//For creating file.
```

But when I want to delete it using

```
Files.delete(path)
```

it gives me message

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**
```

Delete file code ....

```
Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

                Files.delete(file);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException e)
                    throws IOException {
                if (e == null) {
                     Files.delete(dir);
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                } else {
                    // directory iteration failed
                    throw e;
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java 7: Path vs File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903335/java-7-path-vs-file)

Comment: You probably leave the file open after you write to it somewhere in your code. Remember to always close files/streams/etc. after you're done with them. Java 7 provides a neat mechanism called 'try with resources' that takes care of that for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html
I'm afraid nothing more can be said unless you provide more info.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot delete a file which has been locked by your process or another process. On windows, files are locked by default, on linux they have to be lock explicitly.

This example

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("test.log");
Path file = Files.createFile(path);
Files.delete(file);
```

runs with out error

Answer (score 0):

To delete a file, you must obtain the file handler (normally owned by the thread which created it). Thus, If one thread created a file, another thread **CANNOT** delete it.

Make sure, when you delete your file, the server didn't create another thread which is what happens on each server code.

**PS:** If you want more a better answer, you will have to provide more info

Answer (score 0):

Did you close all your writers that use the reference to the given file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swing components to open the file, you could use the `dispose()` method for that component that opens the file.