# File class or Path class, Which is best to use?

Tags: java, java-7, java-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java 7: Path vs File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903335/java-7-path-vs-file)

I am learning about Java file handling. I am reading a book which says that Java 7 has NIO, with the `Path` class, and that we should use that in preference to the `File` class.

Are `Path` and `File` classes the same?

Answer (score 3):

The `File` (and other classes in `java.io.*` are rather old, going back to the early days of Java. They work and they do the job, but they aren't easy to use. The `File` class itself is an encapsulation of a file's filesystem path in addition to certain metadata (read-only status, file size).

Many Java IO operations and classes, such as `FileInputStream` work with the old `File` class, but most of them also accept filenames as `String` instances.

The `Path` class is a better-designed and modern alternative. You can read up about it here: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/Path.html

While `Path` is new, the `File` class is not officially deprecated or obsoleted. I think it's one of those "if it's a new project, use X, otherwise keep on using Y"-things.

So in response to your question: no, they are not the same. `Path` replaces `File` and should be used in new projects.