# Convert object from java.nio.file.Path to java.io.File

Tags: java

I would like to know if it is possible somehow to convert an object that is defined as `java.nio.file.Path` to `java.io.File`

Comment: Duplicate? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26658436/384674

Comment: just call toFile() on Path object

Comment: @Betlista  The referenced post is not a duplicate.  It is a broad question discussing about which API chooses between Pah and File.  There exists maybe a real duplicate. Please refer that if you found it.

Comment: @davidxxx I kindly disagree, in first answer it says "And if you ever need a File object for legacy, just call Path#toFile()", with a small effort it can be found easily...

Comment: @Betlista This point is a side note about compatibility between the two APIs.  I don't think that it is an effort question. Duplicates means that the question has duplicate(s). In many complete answers, you can find information that addresses multiple questions. So I don't think that it is relevant. Don't you think that reading so many lines and posts to know how to convert a Path to File is not efficient ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Both  `java.nio.file.Path` and `java.io.File` classes provides a way to pass from the one to the other.

1) Invoking  `toFile()` on a `Path` object returns a `File` representing it.

[`Path.toFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile--) javadoc :

> Returns a `File` object representing this path. Where this `Path` is
>   associated with the default provider, then this method is equivalent
>   to returning a `File` object constructed with the `String` representation
>   of this path.
>
> If this path was created by invoking the `File` `toPath` method then there
>   is no guarantee that the `File` object returned by this method is equal
>   to the original File.

2) Reversely, invoking `toPath()` on a `File` object returns a `Path` representing it.

[`File.toPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath--) javadoc :

> Returns a `java.nio.file.Path` object constructed from the this abstract
>   path. The resulting `Path` is associated with the default-filesystem.
>
> The first invocation of this method works as if invoking it were
>   equivalent to evaluating the expression:
>
> `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(this.getPath());`
>
> Subsequent invocations of this method return the same `Path`.